# Sqlite3 trigger: add a column

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have one idea to implement in sqlite3. That's is possible to do in trigger alter table with add column from name of new.something?

simple example :

```
CREATE TRIGGER add_something AFTER INSERT ON simple_table 
BEGIN:
    ALTER TABLE second_table add column NEW.simple_name int;
END;
```

When I try this I have syntax error. In postgres I just do EXECUTE, but sqlite is very easy and specific simple database so I don't know how to do this... I try cast to text and concatenate with ''.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use `ALTER TABLE` statements inside a trigger.

To execute a dynamic SQL statement, you would have to register your own function that does whatever you want:

```
CREATE TRIGGER add_something
AFTER INSERT ON simple_table 
BEGIN
    SELECT my_function(NEW.simple_name);
END;
```

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not possible. You can only have INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, and SELECT statements in SQLite triggers (cf [the SQLite documentation on CREATE TRIGGER](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtrigger.html)).